Unable to configure navigation exception when setting up fluent API notation one-to-many with EF Core code-first
Given these entities:
public class MyParent
{
    public required Guid Id { get; set; };
    public required MyChild Child { get; set; };        
}

public class MyChild
{
    public required Guid Id { get; set; };
    public required IEnumerable<MyChildParameter> Parameters { get; set; };     
}

public class MyChildParameter
{
    public required Guid Id { get; set; };
    public required string Value { get; set; };     
}

I am setting up fluent API notations to enrich my domain models so they can be used with EF Core at infrastructure and I uphold the open / closed principle.
I'm using OnModelCreating, but with the notation logic isolated for cleanliness:
internal static class MyCreator()
{
    internal static void CreateMyParent(ModelBuilder mb)
    {
        mb.Entity<MyParent>()
            .HasKey(p => p.Id);

        mb.Entity<MyParent>()
            .ComplexProperty(p => p.Fase)
            .IsRequired();
    }
    
    internal static void CreateMyChild(ModelBuilder mb)
    {
        mb.Entity<MyChild>()
            .HasKey(p => p.Id);

        mb.Entity<MyChild>()
            .Property(p => p.Name)
            .IsRequired();
    }

    internal static void CreateMyChildParameter(ModelBuilder mb)
    {
        mb.Entity<MyChildParameter>()
            .HasKey(p => p.Id);

        mb.Entity<MyChildParameter>()
            .Property(p => p.Value)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}

I have tried to set up a one-to-many relation:
mb.Entity<MyParent>()
    .HasMany(f => f.Parameters)
    .WithOne(p => p.MyParent)
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.MyParentId)
    .IsRequired();

But when I generate my migration I get the following exception:

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'MyContext'. The exception
'Unable to configure navigation 'MyParent.MyChild#MyChild.Parameters'
of type 'IEnumerable' as complex types don't support
navigations. Ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or
by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.' was thrown
while attempting to create an instance.

Ignoring or not mapping isn't an option because I need these entities.
Question: How do I set up a one-to-many relation in a way that avoids this exception?

My guess is that your issue arises because of the IEnumerable collection you're using. IEnumerable exposes a collection only to be iterated on, but not to actually change its contents. Therefore, EF interprets IEnumerable as read only and cannot use it to track changes.
You should be able to fix this by using ICollection as the property's type.
Here's an updated version of your models:
public class MyParent
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid MyChildId { get; set; } // Foreign key property

    public MyChild Child { get; set; } // Reference property to MyChild
}

public class MyChild
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<MyParent> Parents { get; set; } = new List<MyParent>(); // Collection navigation to the related MyParent objects

    public ICollection<MyChildParameter> Parameters { get; set; } = new List<MyChildParameter>(); // Same for parameters
}

public class MyChildParameter
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public Guid MyChildId { get; set; } // foreign key property

    public MyChild MyChild { get; set; } // Reference property to MyChild
}

You can then further specify the relationship, like foreign key and delete behavior by using the Fluent API:
modelBuilder.Entity<MyChildParameter>()
    .HasOne(childParameter => childParameter.MyChild)
    .WithMany(myChild => myChild.Parameters)
    .HasForeignKey(childParameter => childParameter.MyChildId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
    .IsRequired();

If you would like these navigational properties to support lazy loading by EF, you should use the virtual keyword with the collection and reference properties:
public virtual ICollection<MyParent> Parents { get; set; } = [];
public virtual MyChild MyChild { get; set; }

By applying these changes, you should be able to avoid the exception and properly set up the relationships.
For more details, refer to Microsoft's docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/one-to-many#required-one-to-many
